# CTRL+S (or similar) -> Save

Tags: feature-request, usability

I have the annoying habit of hitting CTRL+S when typing into a textbox and pausing for thought.

Is there any way to kind of "circumvent" this habit with some kind of key combination that'll save what you're typing?

Comment: [Drafts are automatically saved every 45 seconds.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238) For a while, Control+S would force a manual save, but [that keyboard shortcut was removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/is-the-save-draft-keyboard-binding-broken/69885#69885).

Answer (score 3):

It sort of exists. Any text that you type in gets autosaved periodically. Now if you want nothing to happen when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> well you can do so using Auto HotKey (.. and becomes a question for Super User)

[image]

Comment: I know it exists, my dilemma is that I keep hitting CTRL+S even with autosave.